# colon placement in Ruby 2.2+

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntactic-sugar

I see colons used two different ways in Ruby

```
:controller => 'pages'
```

and then

```
action: => 'home'
```

I found an explanation here: http://goo.gl/ZKxKVK
it seems that the position doesn't matter, could someone clarify this?

Comment: in the second example you can drop the fat arrow

Comment: also this is a ruby thing not a rails thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it doesn't matter. Since Ruby 1.9 we can use more short form:

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2}
```

But there are some situations where you have to use the longest form, e.g.:

```
h = {1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'}
h = {"One Two" => 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

`action: => 'home'` is not valid syntax.

It should be `action: 'home'` or `:action => 'home'`.

These are equivalent. They generate:

```
{:action=>'home'}
```

Comment: Ruby 2.2 accepts action: => 'home' as valid syntax

Comment: On Ruby 2.2.3 I get: `{action: =>'home'}
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected =>` How are you using it?